# Docker compose yaml - Volumes issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been following [this docker tutorial](http://tech.osteel.me/posts/2015/12/18/from-vagrant-to-docker-how-to-use-docker-for-local-web-development.html), but because it's really out of date today, I cannot completely follow it. Once I had this `docker-compose.yml` file working:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - 80:80
    links:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./www/html:/var/www/html

  php:
    image: php:7.0-fpm
    expose:
        - 9000
    volumes:
        - ./www/html:/var/www/html
```

It did ran successfully.

It didn't work when I was trying to extract volumes info into the separate property [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference).

I've tried several approaches and combinations, but all have failed.
Please give me a hint how to specify it properly.

Folder structure like this:

```
nginx
  default.conf
  Dockerfile
www
  html
    index.php
docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: are you running your docker containers inside a VM / docker machine ?

Comment: @diginoise I'm not sure. On windows 10 I've installed docker and nothing more

Comment: that narrows it down... do you use Windows Subsytem for Linux (WSL) or Hyper-V VM?

Comment: @diginoise I don't believe so

Comment: ok, did you try using absolute paths? also make sure your Docker for Win has Shared Paths enabled: https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c

Answer (score 1):

Host volumes, aka bind mounts, don't need to have a separate volumes section at the top level. The volumes section is only needed for named volumes. In fact the only way you can use the volumes top level is with a named volume.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to actually implement that?

Comment: Since your data is on your host, you wouldn't use a named volume. Docker's documentation on using volumes is available here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/

Comment: So the only true way (in this case) is to use my former approach?

Comment: That's correct, you only define the host volume in the service definition, not in the top level named volume section.